# Huawei 4G modem on Ubuntu 18 modem-manager couldn't get bus: Could not connect: Permission denied

Tags: 18.04, huawei

I am trying to get 4G (UK) working on my Ubuntu 18 server. Specifically Huawei ME909s-120 mini-pcie on APU3 board by pcengine.  The outputs below should describe the details. Very short version of the specific problem:

- attempting to use modem-manager to setup the 4g-modem following this
  https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/modem-manager/docs/installation
- fails at sudo mmcli -L with error: couldn't get bus: Could not
  connect: Permission denied

It feels like a USB device conflict ... but I don't know how to troubleshoot further.  All advice welcomed. Regards

Jack

**Hardware & OS:**

- APU3C4 3x Gigabit LAN, Quad Core CPU, 16GB SSD, 4GB RAM
- wle600vx wireless WiFi kit
- Huawei ME909s-120
- OS: Description: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Server

**Details/command outputs below**

```
jacks1@apu3b:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1566
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1567
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 156b
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1537
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller (rev 01)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1580
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1581
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1582
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1583
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1584
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1585
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA986x/988x 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
jacks1@apu3b:~$ 
jacks1@apu3b:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:15c1 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
jacks1@apu3b:~$ 
jacks1@apu3b:~$ dmesg |grep tty
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-55-generic root=/dev/mapper/apu3b--vg-root ro console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-55-generic root=/dev/mapper/apu3b--vg-root ro console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.000000] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    4.605171] 00:02: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    4.633344] 00:03: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    4.661510] serial8250: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    4.690061] serial8250: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[   16.199614] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   16.200315] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   16.203640] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   16.212321] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[   16.212966] usb 1-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
jacks1@apu3b:~$ 
jacks1@apu3b:~$ sudo mmcli -V
mmcli 1.8.0
jacks1@apu3b:~$ sudo mmcli -L
error: couldn't get bus: Could not connect: Permission denied
jacks1@apu3b:~$ 
jacks1@apu3b:~$ sudo snap connections modem-manager
Interface      Plug                 Slot                   Notes
modem-manager  -                    modem-manager:service  -
modem-manager  modem-manager:mmcli  -                      -
jacks1@apu3b:~$ 
jacks1@apu3b:~$ 
jacks1@apu3b:~$ sudo systemctl status snap.modem-manager.modemmanager.service 
● snap.modem-manager.modemmanager.service - Service for snap application modem-manager.modemmanager
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap.modem-manager.modemmanager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enable
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-08-01 14:38:54 BST; 7min ago
 Main PID: 1034 (ModemManager)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4638)
   CGroup: /system.slice/snap.modem-manager.modemmanager.service
           └─1034 /snap/modem-manager/267/usr/sbin/ModemManager --debug --log-level=DEBUG

Aug 01 14:39:31 apu3b ModemManager[1034]: <debug> [1564666771.737155] Couldn't initialize interface: 'OMA not
Aug 01 14:39:31 apu3b ModemManager[1034]: <debug> [1564666771.737556] Couldn't initialize interface: 'Firmwar
Aug 01 14:39:31 apu3b ModemManager[1034]: <info>  [1564666771.737944] Modem: state changed (unknown -> disabl
Aug 01 14:39:31 apu3b ModemManager[1034]: <debug> [1564666771.738459] modem properly initialized
Aug 01 14:39:31 apu3b ModemManager[1034]: <debug> [1564666771.741105] [device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00
Aug 01 14:39:31 apu3b ModemManager[1034]: <debug> [1564666771.741186] [device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00
Aug 01 14:39:31 apu3b ModemManager[1034]: <debug> [1564666771.741258] [device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00
Aug 01 14:39:31 apu3b ModemManager[1034]: <debug> [1564666771.741350] (ttyUSB0) device open count is 0 (close
Aug 01 14:39:31 apu3b ModemManager[1034]: <debug> [1564666771.741429] (ttyUSB0) closing serial port...
Aug 01 14:39:31 apu3b ModemManager[1034]: <debug> [1564666771.761686] (ttyUSB0) serial port closed
jacks1@apu3b:~$
```

Enabled debug mode on ModemManager - I'll attach the output shortly. Thanks again

Comment: Here is the debug output  https://pastebin.com/q9Ly8ZZS .

The specific WARN messages are:

Aug 01 14:39:27 apu3b ModemManager[1034]: <warn>  [1564666767.345117] Could not grab port (tty/ttyUSB4): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyUSB4', unhandled serial type'

Comment: really interesting thread here: https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=106164 seem there are issues but not necessarily Ubuntu related.